# How to create multi columns tables report with reportskit in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to create multi columns table report with reportskit in rails. I tried a lot of ways but anything I didn't find right solution. Could anyone please help me? How to do multi columns table report with reportskit?

I tried on dimension configuration but it isn't effected on multi column report. Then I tried a lot of configuration on yaml file. This is the reportskit official website https://www.reportskit.co/.

In Model file,

```
reports_kit do
    aggregation :average_time_to_publish, [:average, 'sale.created_at - posts.updated_at']
    contextual_filter :for_author, ->(relation, context_params) { relation.where(sale_id: context_params[:sale_id]) }
    dimension :approximate_views_count, group: 'ROUND(sale.views_count, -1)'
    filter :is_published, :boolean, conditions: ->(relation) { relation.where(status: 'published') }
  end
```

In YML file,

```
measure: sale
filters:
- key: sale_id
- key: cashier_name
- key: created_at
  criteria:
    operator: between
    value: "-3M - now"
dimensions:
- key: sale_id
  label: SALE ID
  limit: 5
- key: created_at
  label: CREATED AT
  limit: 5
format: table
```

Actual Result,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdHsz.png)
Expected Result,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmLQz.png)

Comment: I edited your question to make it a little more readable: you should clearly select and indicate which blocks of text are actually code blocks or not. Please fix formatting if it is no longer ok. Please supply a link to `reportskit` (for the people that have never used it or do not know it).

Comment: Hi nathavda, Thank you so much for this.